# Use a local file as the set_image file discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am aware that in discord.py, you can make the `set_image` of an embed a url of an image. But, I want to use a local file on my computer for the `set_image` instead of a url of an image.

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
embed.set_image(url = "https://example.com/image.png") #this is for set_image using url
```

How can I achieve this? Is there another function or something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok I just got it. The code for it is the following:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00) #creates embed
file = discord.File("path/to/image/file.png", filename="image.png")
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

The **only** thing you should be changing is line 2 where it says `"path/to/image/file.png"`

**Note:** on lines 2 and 3, there is an `image.png`. Fret not about it since thats what Discord is calling the uploaded file (Example: I have a file called `duck.png`, Discord uploads it to their servers as `image.png`). So you don't need to change the `image.png` part. However, if you are using a file that the specific extension matters, remember to change the `image.png` to the desired extension. An example of a file that requires a specific extension is a GIF so remember to change `image.png` to for example, an `image.gif`if you are using a GIF.

You can read more here at discord.py's official documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image

Comment: @AnchithAcharya My bad my answer wasn't as detailed. I just went ahead and edited it. Change `image.png` to `image.gif`. That filename is what the file is called on Discord's servers. In your scenario, you were calling a local gif file, but were uploading it as a `.png`

Comment: Nah, that I could infer from the syntax. I did try with .gif but the program just stopped at channel/ctx.send without even returning any error message. I tried uploading the gif as a file, but with similar results. It just went into the send method and never returned. Or so I thought. _Minutes_ later, the gif popped up. I thought the flow was abruptly stopping inside the send method when infact, it hadn't stopped at all and was uploading all the time. Guess uploading using a url is better than using a local file, for a gif.

Comment: Your code snippet redefines the embed on line 3, which loses the colour, title and description you set on line 1.

Comment: @SamRockett My bad. I have changed my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: How would do this for a file stored in a sqlite3 database? I can fetch the file into a correct format for discord `file = discord.File(BytesIO(row_name), filename='file_name.png')` but I can't get the file to be shown

Answer (score 3):

Peppa's answer is right, but I must add that if you are doing this for a gif, it is better to pass an actual url to set_image than the `attachments://image.gif` url. Because everytime you do the latter and call ctx.send or channel.send, the gif has to get uploaded first before being sent. This may take very long (around  2-3 minutes for a 5MB gif, for me) if your gif is not compressed. Whereas by passing a url you can get the gif in a matter of seconds.