# Python 3, Discord Webhook, adding photo to embed message

Tags: python, discord, embed

I have a script which goes to: https://civilprotection.gov.gr/arxeio-imerision-xartwn
and grabs the url of the most recent map, like this:
https://civilprotection.gov.gr/sites/default/files/2023-05/230524.jpg
It then adds it to an embed message and posts it to a Discord channel.

Everything worked like a charm until 2 days ago. It now posts the message but although the url of the picture is correct the picture is missing from the message.

So 1. I get the correct url of the picture
2. I save the url to a variable
3. Use embed.set_image(url=map_url) for the picture.

Anyone could guess why this doesn’t work anymore even if I copy paste the correct url (skipping the procedure where I create the url using code)?

Already tried using different url and it worked. Dunno why…
Maybe it’s website related?

Comment: Maybe [save the image locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8286449/9731347), and then try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64689845/9731347).