# Discord Bot Image not in the embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Below is an image of the image loading outside of the embed. I'm attempting to put the image inside of the embed. I'm also using `.set_image` for the embed as well.

[image: Image of image being outside of the embed]

Minimal reproducible example:

```
@bot.command(name='abrir')
async def abrir_case(ctx, case_name: str):
    user_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    current_balance = get_balance(user_id)

    if current_balance < 10:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Erro ao abrir o caso", description=":x: Você não possui saldo suficiente para abrir o caso.", color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
        return

    update_balance(user_id, current_balance - 10)

    case_folder_path = f"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\bot\\Itens\\{case_name}"
    
    if not os.path.exists(case_folder_path):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Erro ao abrir o caso", description=":x: Este caso não existe.", color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
        return

    total_weight = sum(RARITY_CHANCES.values())

    chosen_rarity = random.choices(list(RARITY_CHANCES.keys()), weights=[RARITY_CHANCES[rarity] / total_weight for rarity in RARITY_CHANCES])[0]

    rarity_folder_path = os.path.join(case_folder_path, chosen_rarity)

    items = os.listdir(rarity_folder_path)

    chosen_item = random.choice(items)

    desguaste = random.uniform(0, 1)

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Caso Aberto", description=f"Você abriu o caso {case_name} e obteve:", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="Item", value=chosen_item[:-4], inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Raridade", value=chosen_rarity, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="DESGUASTE", value=desguaste, inline=False)

    item_image_path = os.path.join(rarity_folder_path, chosen_item)
    try:
        if os.path.exists(item_image_path) and os.path.isfile(item_image_path):
            file = discord.File(item_image_path, filename=chosen_item)
            embed.set_image(url=f"attachment://{chosen_item}")
            await ctx.reply(file=file, embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
        print(f"Error sending image: {e}")
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

I was trying to get the image on the embed message.

Answer (score 1):

The docs say:

> Discord special-cases uploading an image attachment and using it within an embed so that it will not display separately, but instead in the embed’s thumbnail, image, footer or author icon.
>
> To do so, upload the image normally with abc.Messageable.send(), and
> set the embed’s image URL to attachment://image.png, where image.png
> is the filename of the image you will send.

See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#local-image).

[image: Image of it outside the embed]

Just like the docs say, use the same file name too.

```py
@client.command(name='abrir')
async def abrir_case(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Test", color=0x00ff00)

    item_image_path = 'space-512702.png'
    if os.path.exists(item_image_path) and os.path.isfile(item_image_path):
        file = discord.File(item_image_path)
        embed.set_image(url=f"attachment://{item_image_path}")  # then use that file as the embed url
        await ctx.reply(file=file, embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

The above outputs the following:

[image: Working example]

This works because the actual image path in `discord.File` is the exact same as the image's attachment path. You're using the `item_image_path` which is different from the `chosen_item` and therefore doesn't work. After answering this, I realize this is very similar to the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64689845/15982771). It might be a duplicate, but your problem is slightly different.

Comment: But the command its like a case opening and the image its the item that the user will recive so it can't be a specific image

Comment: @GodNpc I'm not sure what you mean. I don't have access to your full code and therefore can't do a full reconstruction and solution based off that. Stack Overflow is for the public & my question is written that way. If you fully read and understand my question, you should be able to figure it out.